# Java - Appending to Buffered image via createGraphics is not working

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I'm clearly missing something here. I'm trying to cut a slice from an original image, move the remaining larger piece to the left and then append the cut out slice to the right side. Marquee style.

*In the attached images, the ORIGINAL image is on top and the resulting BufferedImage from the drawImage functions is on the bottom.*

[image]

This works:

```
    try {
        originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\temp\\scanner.png"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    int sliceSize = 23;
    scrolledImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = scrolledImage.createGraphics();

    leftSlice = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    leftSlice = originalImage.getSubimage(0,0,sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight());
    g2.drawImage(leftSlice,originalImage.getWidth()  - sliceSize,0,sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight(),null);
    rightSlice = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    rightSlice = originalImage.getSubimage(sliceSize,0,originalImage.getWidth() - sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight());
    g2.drawImage(rightSlice,0,0,originalImage.getWidth() - sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight(),null);
    g2.dispose();
```

Trying to append to the leftslice with the rightslice does not work:

```
    leftSlice = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    leftSlice = originalImage.getSubimage(0,0,sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight());
    Graphics2D left2D = leftSlice.createGraphics();
    rightSlice = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    rightSlice = originalImage.getSubimage(sliceSize,0,originalImage.getWidth() - sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight());
    left2D.drawImage(rightSlice,0,0,originalImage.getWidth() - sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight(),null);
    left2D.dispose();
```

This is what I get with the second code:
[image]

So..it seems to be over-writing the original image. How is that possible when I've implicitly created a new BufferedImage (and createGraphics) and then instructed it to write over new one? Something about the getSubimage I suspect...

I'm just trying to eliminate the need for the extra steps and Buffered images, since this code will be used in many places for small animated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSubimage() shares the same image does not create a new one - if you read the doc.

So be very very careful with using getSubimage().

This is wasteful (since we are talking about this level of detail):

```
leftSlice = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(),originalImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
leftSlice = originalImage.getSubimage(0,0,sliceSize,originalImage.getHeight());
```

creating an image by constructor and then going and overwriting that address with something else. But not a big deal if you don't care about space and in terms of correctness.

getSubimage() will affect your correctness as you have seen..

Comment: Thanks. I didn't click on the method to see all the details. The overview of the method doesn't mention this fact.

I find this a little strange, though. What happens to the new BufferedImage that was created if you immediately change the pointers to the original image anyway?

I changed it to use the scrolledImage and then drawImage with rightSlice, and then leftSlice. works fine.